# Why does findmany() not work here - Lumen/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm trying to use findmany() on a collection, I checked whether it is a collection or not with this:

```
if ($join instanceof Collection) {
  log::info("deemed collection");
}else{
  log::info("not deemed collection");
}
```

While it seems to be a collection, I still get the error:

```
BadMethodCallException

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::findmany does not exist.
```

When I try to use findmany() on it, like so:

```
$join = $join->findmany(1);
```

The $join was created this way:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->get();
```

Where `$permittedTables` is an array of tablenames, so the collection can consist of any number and combination of tables.

Why can't I use the findmany() method from this collection? It should be accessible from collections, shouldnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `findMany` method on the collection, only [find](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_find).

You can call [findMany](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findMany) on the querybuilder before retrieving the records from the database, something like:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->findMany([1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$join = $join->findMany([1,2,3]);

findMany works with array of Id.

and the findMany should be in camel case.